# Windows Phone 7 longlistselector

Tags: windows-phone-7

Good day,
I have toolkit LongListSelector and i want programatically set the element from existing ones. I have tried by making SelectedItem, but it does not highlight elements from the LongList. Can anyone share how can i do this ?

Comment: You want to programmatically do *what*? you must change the visual states in order to highlight selected item.

Comment: I have a complete LongListSelector, but no items selected. I have previously selected item stored in settings and when it loads next time I want to highlight that item and preferrably also scrol to it atuomatically.

Comment: You can find how to scroll to selected item by searching either internet or this site.

Answer (score 0):

As Toni Petrina mentioned, try searching in net. Lots of blogs like the followings will help you,

http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/wpapps/Highlight-a-selected-item-30ced444

http://www.getcodesamples.com/src/9A9E24E9